# return Caffe model results to a html web page

Tags: html, opencv, python-3.5

I have a Caffe model which detects objects on a video and show the results as bounding boxes and class lable's of each object. I'm using opencv function "cv2.imshow()" to show the results but I want to show this result on a html web page. I'm not using any frameworks link django.

how should I do this?

this is part of my code I want to show its result on a web page:

```
# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
# grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
# to have a maximum width of 400 pixels
#frame = vs.read()
ret, frame = cap.read()
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

# grab the frame dimensions and convert it to a blob
(h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (400, 300)),
    0.008, (400, 300), 128)

# pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and predictions
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()

# loop over the detections
for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
    # the prediction
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    if confidence > treshHold:
        # extract the index of the class label from the
        # `detections`, then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of
        # the bounding box for the object
        idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

        # draw the prediction on the frame
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx],
            confidence * 100)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
            COLORS[idx], 2)
        y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)

# show the output frame
cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

# if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
if key == ord("q"):
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Compose html page, insert necessary links, write result to a file and you are done.
Check here for example: [link](http://python.zirael.org/ch-dynamic_pages.html)